# There exist a functions' space for compact-supported real-valued continuous functions that are smooth except at the boundaries???

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, special-functions, piecewise-continuity

I want to know if there exists an space for time-limited bounded continuous functions (at least one-variable ones), like the space of Bump functions $C_c^\infty$, but for functions that doesn't have to start or finish at $f(t_0)=f(t_F) = 0$ (so, are discontinuous at the boundaries - points of measure zero).

Specifically, I want to know the name of the space that tightly/exclusively contains these functions to look for references and their properties: real one-variable non-constant functions of the form:
$$f(t) = x(t)\cdot(\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))$$ where $\theta(t)$ is the unitary step function, $t_0 < t_F$ (if required, assume is defined only for $t_0 \leq t \leq t_F$), $f(t_0)\neq 0$ or $f(t_F)\neq 0$ or both, and $x(t)$ is a "fully" continuous and smooth non-constant real-valued one-variable function $ x(t) \in C^\infty$.

An example of "bump function" $\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$:
$$ f(t)= e^{1-\frac{1}{1-t^2}},\text{  }|t|\leq 1$$

Example of "time-limited bounded function" $\notin C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$:
$$ f(t)= e^{1-\frac{1}{1-t^2}},\text{  }0\leq t\leq 1$$

In some places I have found some "issues" about how the space of Bump functions is defined:

In some places they say is the space of compact-supported smooth functions $C_c^\infty$, but in other places they also required that they have to fulfill the requirements to be a "Mollifier" (more restricted, since it require that the function must behave as a Dirac delta function in the limit $\lim_{\eta \to 0} \frac{f(\frac{t}{\eta})}{\eta^n}=\delta(t)$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(t) dt =1$, or even that $f(t) \geq 0, \forall t$ and $\max_t f(t) = 1$).

So I am going to explicitly differentiate the space of Bump functions $C_c^\infty$ from the space of "Mollifiers", in here, lets say its $C_0^\infty$.

PS: Please, if you can, create a TAG for "bump-functions", there a lot of related questions and I don't know where to "place them". Beforehand, thanks you very much.

---

**Added later**

I think I found a method that could help to make these kind of spaces of time-limited function by avoiding the discontinuity of the functions in the borders of the compact-support... please review it on my second answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f) question.

**2nd Added Later**

I have found the following paper named "[Finite time differential equations](https://www.sci-hub.se/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832)" by V. T. Haimo (1985), where continuous time differential equations with finite-duration solutions are studied, an it is stated the following:

*"One notices immediately that finite time differential equations cannot be Lipschitz at the origin. As all solutions reach zero in finite time, there is non-uniqueness of solutions through zero in backwards time. This, of course, violates the uniqueness condition for solutions of Lipschitz differential equations."*

Since, linear differential equations have solutions that are unique, and finite-duration solutions aren´t, finite-duration phenomena models must be non-linear to show the required behavior (non meaning this, that every non-linear dynamic system support finite-duration solutions).

The paper also show which conditions must fulfill the non-linear differential equation to support finite-duration solutions, at least for first and second order scalar ODEs.

Since one-variable scalar finite-duration functions are example of one-variable compact-supported functions, I want to know if this issue related to the non-uniqueness of the solutions (which, if I have understood it right, it means that more than one answer could behave as the intended function in the specific compact-support, don´t knowing now how it could be possible, maybe behaving different outside the compact-support?), could be instantly discarding the possibility of building a space of finite-duration functions (or more widely speaking, of non-smooth compact-supported functions). Hope someone can comment about it.

Comment: When you write $C^\infty_c,$ what is the domain space? Often it's $\mathbb{R}^n,$ but your example $f(t)= {\cos^2\left(t\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)},\ |t|\leq 1$ is not in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: @md2perpe I take that example from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821552/zeroes-of-the-fourier-transform-of-bump-functions) and adjusted to be in the interval $[-1; 1]$, so, Could you explain why is not a bump function? (is actually what I am trying to understand)

Comment: Another indication that you'll need to refine your expectations: finite linear combinations of such functions can have finitely-many jump discontinuities... and infinite linear combinations could have infinitely-many. Do you really want/need such functions... or, for example, would you really prefer functions that are continuous except at "endpoints", etc.? There may be problems with making that a vector space...

Comment: @paulgarrett I want to understand the kind of functions that model physical phenomena: reading about Bump Functions, I realize that every continuous and differentiable signal that has a starting point, and endpoint, and bounded energy, can't be analytical, so every solution I have seen through standard functions are really approximations. I am self studying from Wikipedia and I found some issues/contradictions on the definitions so I am a bit lost. I read about Bump functions which are within $C_c^\infty$, but it required to begin and end at $0$, and this is too restrictive to model anything.

Comment: Where on that page does it say that a function like that is a bump function?

Comment: @md2perpe is a function defined in a close interval $|t| <1$ (compacted-supported I believe is named), bounded (since $\max = 1$ and $\min = 0$), is smooth a think since its derivatives will be always combinations of trigonometric functions, and in the edges is smooth since $\lim_{t \to \pm 1} f(t) = 0$ and $\lim_{t \to \pm 1} \frac{df(t)}{dt} = 0$. In the mentioned link they use in the comments the function $(1+\cos(x))^2$ as example of a bump function which has known Fourier transform in closed form... Can you explained why that was a bump function and why my example is not?

Comment: Okay, they say that it is compactly supported, but it is not in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ as you write since $f^{(4)}$ is not continuous at $x=\pm\pi.$

Comment: @paulgarrett I was thinking about the linear combinations you mention, but I believe if they are finitely many, it will be a similar problem that the defining of Cumulative Distributions functions through Cadlag functions, if they are finitely many jumps it going to be a definable thing since its Lebesgue measure its still going to be finite.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks, now I understand that for be a Bump function it also has to fulfill $\lim_{t \to \partial t} \frac{d^n f(t)}{dt^n} = 0$.. I will change the selected example to properly asked the question.

Comment: @paulgarrett I think I found a method that could help to make these kind of spaces of time-limited function by avoiding the discontinuity of the functions in the borders of the compact-support... please review it on my second answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f) question.